Can't find the title of the movie that happens in white/blank land
I need some help with a movie title.
When I was a kid, I used to watch tv but i think i didn't understand the movies the right way. So nostalgia hit me and i want to rewatch the one movie that popped into my mind now.
I don't know the title or the cast, the memory is really blurry. I just know some information. If you know the name of the movie, please answer this question.
A part of the film happens in a white blank area/land, where there is nothing at all, only white endless land. In that land there are (If i remember correctly) 2 people. I think they are friends at first and they notice they can use their imagination and "build" things. If they imagined something, it would appear there. But as ste story goes by, these friends argued and imagined, that other peoples body parts dissapear. And it dissapeared.
Sorry if you don't understand what I want to say. The movie sounds pretty bad, but I still want to rewatch it again.
Thanks for helping.
Ps: I think the genre would be drama/comedy, but dont trust me on that. (sci-fi too)
The spoken language was English, and the year of release below year 2000 I think.

It's Nothing (2003), starring David Hewlett pre-Stargate Atlantis. 
I previously IDed this for someone else here some time ago, but the original asker disappeared without confirming.
Trailer:



Bold parts match:

The film tells the story of two good friends and housemates, Andrew
  (Andrew Miller), an agoraphobic travel agent, and Dave (David
  Hewlett), a loser who works in an office. Dave is fired from his job
  after his girlfriend frames him for embezzlement, Andrew is falsely
  accused of attempted child molestation, and their house is to be
  demolished by day's end. Both of them hide inside the house as police,
  city officials, and outraged neighbors surround it. Dave and Andrew
  open their front door and discover that the entire world beyond their
  house is gone, replaced with a featureless white void.
Eventually, after a simple test reveals that the nothingness
  surrounding them holds a flat, featureless, and somewhat springy
  surface "like tofu", they set out across the empty plane in order to
  explore their new surroundings, leaving items behind as a means of
  getting back. After running out of items to leave as a trail, they
  lose track of their path. Wandering leads them to what appears to be
  another house, but they have simply wandered back home.
Panic begins to set in again when Andrew realizes that the house is
  completely out of food. Andrew glances around the room, eventually
  stopping and glaring at a noisy clock on the wall; within a few
  seconds it disappears. Andrew drops a stack of overdue bills in front
  of Dave, and within seconds the bills abruptly disappear. Dave puts
  one last theory to test, managing to hate away his need for food.
Dave still expresses some concern over Andrew's remaining phobias,
  questioning why the phobias still exist when there's nothing left to
  fear. Reluctantly, Andrew reveals that he was abused and tormented by
  his parents as a child. With some urging from Dave he hates away the
  memory of each traumatic childhood event as he recounts it; when he is
  finally done he is no longer phobic and much more confident in
  himself. Unfortunately this change alters Andrew's personality and
  leads to friction between the two friends, finally building into an
  outright confrontation. They decide they can no longer share the same
  house, and opt to determine who keeps it by playing a match of their
  favorite fighting game. Dave loses, and is exiled with his possessions
  to reside out in the nothingness.
Things become very tense with Dave's departure. Dave attempts to
  engage Andrew in conversation repeatedly, even performing the national
  anthem for his self-created nation (its borders marked by a line of
  his possessions), all to no avail. After several days Dave comes into
  Andrew's house much happier and explains his sudden change of mood: he
  has hated away his anger at Andrew; all Andrew needs to do is hate
  away his anger at Dave and things will be back to normal. Andrew
  refuses, quite content to be angry at Dave. Dave hates away his anger
  several times as Andrew rebuffs and outright insults him, but his
  patience finally wears thin, leading Dave to hate away one of Andrew's
  possessions. Andrew retaliates by hating away one of Dave's
  possessions, and the situation escalates until everything including
  the house is hated away.
Dave walks away, assuming the argument is finished, but falls over
  suddenly as his feet begin to disappear; Andrew is hating them away.
  He turns and retaliates, hating away Andrew's legs, and the situation
  escalates again until all that is left of the two are their
  disembodied heads. Refusing to give up the fight, Andrew and Dave
  manage to turn themselves and (by bouncing) charge at each other,
  headbutting each other repeatedly until they finally stop, exhausted.
  Their anger abated, Dave and Andrew make up, agree to be best friends
  again, and set off to explore the nothingness. As they bounce away
  into the white void they remark how they both had always thought that
  their bodies were somehow holding them back.
In a post-credits scene, an obviously older Dave and Andrew – still
  disembodied heads – are sleeping when they are awakened by a popping
  sound, followed by a loud clamoring of voices and noise. As the unseen
  source of the clamoring gets louder and closer the two scream.


Thats it! A thousand times thanks. I'm very satisfied, good and fast job.
